# Why can't I add new divs with jQuery in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to dynamically generate page content based on a CSV file.

Everything reads fine, but it seems I can't create new divs on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "celebs.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
             var newData = processData(data);
             for (var i in newData){
                buildCeleb(newData[i]);
             }
        },
        error: function(){
             alert('error');
        }
     });
function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
    var lines = [];
    for (var i=1; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {
            var tarr = [];
            for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
                tarr.push(headers[j]+":"+data[j]);
            }
            lines.push(tarr);
        }
    }
    // alert(lines);
    return lines;
}
function buildCeleb(celeb){
var name = celeb[0].split(':')[1];
var facebook = celeb[1].split(':')[1];
var twitter = celeb[2].split(':')[1];
var reach = celeb[3].split(':')[1];
var profession = celeb[4].split(':')[1];
var photo = celeb[5].split(':')[1];
$("#cy-container").append("<div></div>");
}
});
 //--><!]]></script>
```

It's the `$("#cy-container").append("<div></div>");` part that seems to be broken. If I replace the div with say, `name` or `facebook`, or even a hardcoded string literal, it works and appears on the page.

Now, I don't know much about Wordpress, but is there something wrong with what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried to use "Noconflitct"?
Jquery has a lot of issues with custom themes which includes Jquery.
So use : "$j=jQuery.noConflict();" and replace your "$" by "$j".

Comment: That can't be it - it works fine when using string literals.

Comment: Could you provide a sample format of your celebs.csv file?

Comment: The CSV file isn't the issue here...without it, I still cannot add a new div to the page.

Answer (score 0):

That div should have **some value inside** it to be displayed..
Try giving

```
$("#cy-container").append("<div>Hello "+name+"</div>");
```

Comment: yes, I've tried that. it seems as though the script "breaks" - the `alert` at the beginning of the script no longer fires when I try to add a new div.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$("#cy-container").append($("<div></div>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#cy-container').append("<div/>");
```